# Track TCP/UDP Connections for a Program

Tags: debugging, udp, tcp

What is the best way to track a application's internet communication? I've used [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) with Internet Explorer in the past (with great success on SSL tests). But I'm not finding a easy way to track all the communication between a specific windows program, and the sockets it creates with the operating system Windows 7, 64 bit.

Fiddler would work great, unfortunately, this program would require me to setup a proxy. I'm not sure how to do that for the program I'm trying to read all the communication from. And I'm pretty sure then I'd get the "bucket" for every socket connected to my machine, which would be difficult to filter I believe.

Netstat seems to only give the remote locations being accessed, and not much else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give [Port Reporter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837243) a try for this.